# localtime not actually giving localtime

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pyephem

there's obviously a time module that works in combination with this problem, but I have not found it yet.
I'm simply trying to use Pyephem on a Raspberry Pi to find out what time sunrise and sunset is for my latitude longitude coordinates.
the code is quite simply this:

```
import ephem
import datetime 
import time
now = datetime.datetime.now()
gmNow = time.mktime(time.localtime()) 
Vancouver = ephem.Observer()
Vancouver.lat = 49.2878
Vancouver.horizon = 0
Vancouver.lon = -123.0502
Vancouver.elevation = 80
Vancouver.date = now
# Vancouver.date = time.localtime()

sun = ephem.Sun()

print("sunrise is at",ephem.localtime(Vancouver.next_rising(sun)))
print("sunset is going to be at ",ephem.localtime(Vancouver.next_setting(sun)))
print("now is ",now)
print("gmNow is",gmNow)
```

what exports, when that runs is wrong by 8 hours though.  so it appears that the 
    ephem.localtime() is not actually running.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo python3 vivarium_sun.py 
sunrise is at 2014-09-19 12:55:56.000004
sunset is going to be at  2014-09-19 00:52:30.000004
now is  2014-09-19 06:22:24.014859
gmNow is 1411132944.0
```

It's driving me nuts, and it's obviously one of those simple things once it's figured out, so I'm going to the hive mind here.

EDIT**  Just typing 'date' into the command line of the Raspberry Pi returns the following:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ date
Fri Sep 19 18:41:42 PDT 2014
```

which is accurate.

Comment: you should use `time.time()` instead of `time.mktime(time.localtime())` the later might return wrong result during DST transitions.

Comment: see [Sunrise / set calculations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2539597/4279)

Comment: Python relies on your operating system settings to determine what local time means. So we should begin by leaving Python out of the equation: if you type the command `date` on your Raspberry Pi, what is its output — could you paste it into your question for us?

Comment: yup, you can see from the "now is .." comment second from the bottom that datetime.datetime.now() is returning the accurate localtime.
Also, the date or time command from the command line returns accurate to localtime.

Comment: also, the difference between the result of time.mktime(time.localtime())  and time.time() is gmNow is 1411178199.0
timetimeNow is  1411178199.284297

Comment: some cities (not many) are already know to `ephem` therefore instead of setting coordinates, in your specific case you can create an observer with `ephem.city('Vancouver')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `datetime.utcnow()` to the observer instead of your local time.

`ephem` expects `latitude` and `longitude` in radians if passed as floats, use strings instead:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

import ephem

now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
Vancouver = ephem.Observer()
Vancouver.lat = '49.2878'
Vancouver.horizon = 0
Vancouver.lon = '-123.0502'
Vancouver.elevation = 80
Vancouver.date = now
sun = ephem.Sun(Vancouver)

print("sunrise is at", ephem.localtime(Vancouver.next_rising(sun)))
print("sunset is going to be at ", 
      ephem.localtime(Vancouver.next_setting(sun)))
print("now is ",now.astimezone())
```

#### Output

```
sunrise is at 2014-09-20 06:55:38.000005
sunset is going to be at  2014-09-19 19:16:38.000004
now is  2014-09-19 19:15:04.171486-07:00
```

Comment: I added this, and the result of datetime.utcnow() is an error:   timeUTC = datetime.utcnow()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'utcnow'

Comment: use `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: dang, nope. sunrise is at 2014-09-20 12:53:17.000005
sunset is going to be at  2014-09-20 00:54:27.000005
now is  2014-09-20 02:01:28.962811
it switched the 'now' to UTC time, but still fails

Comment: @Octoth0rpe: you should also fix longitude, latitude. I've updated the answer with complete code example

Comment: YES!!
Thank you.  See?  Something simple.  Argh. 'forest for the trees'.  I never even thought of that and went all rambo looking for other datetime, date, timedate, etc packages.  Thanks again!